# Analytic function on the whole plane, positive imaginary part, what can it be?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, analyticity

Part (a): The function f is analytic in the whole plane with positive imaginary part.  What can it be?

Part (b): What if all you know is that the imaginary part of f tends to 0 at infinity?

what we know:

For part(a):
Write f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)

u(x,y) and v(x,y) are both harmonic; in particular, they are harmonic conjugates to each other.  So, Uxx+Uyy=0, and similarly for v.

The Cauchy-Riemann equations hold: $$Ux = Vy$$
$$Uy=-Vx$$

Since f has positive imaginary part, then v(x,y) $>/=$ 0, and its partial derivatives, Vx and Vy are both non-negative.

What more can I say about this function, for part(a)?

Some natural (or maybe not so natural?) guesses would be that f is a constant, or a polynomial, or an exponential function, since we know that f is entire.  But, at the moment, I can't seem to extract any more information from the question itself.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Positive imaginary part - that means the image is contained in the upper half-plane. But the upper half-plane is conformally equivalent to an open disk. So after composing with a suitable mapping, $f$ takes its values in a disk. What does that tell you?

Comment: Or, if you seem to know only the very definition of *complex* analytic function (i.e. real and imaginary part are harmonic conjugates), what do you know about non-negative harmonic functions in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @Mike, applying your hint and making my best guess, I'd say that, consider the standard mapping phi: upper half plane -> unit disk, compose it with f, then phi(f(z)) takes values in the open disk, which is bounded.  I'd now like to argue that since f is entire and bounded, and by Liouville's theorem, we conclude that f is a constant.  But, that may not be correct, since, it's really phi(f(z)) that is bounded - not f(z), which lives in the upper half space.  Also, f is entire, but I don't think phi(f(z)) is entire.  Am I sort of on the right track?

Comment: "Lebron", what is the domain of $\phi(f(z))$?

Comment: The upper half plane...

Comment: @wisefool: I see that there is actually a Liouville's theorem for harmonic functions, which are considered real analogues to holomorphic functions.  The theorem states that if a harmonic function is defined on all of R^n and is either bounded above or below, then it is a constant.  However, I don't know how well-known this theorem is - I certainly don't recall learning this in class lectures or from the books of Ahlfors or Brown and Churchill, so perhaps I should use some other information from your hint, in order to develop a better explanation of why f is constant.

Comment: No, that is not the domain of $\phi(f(z))$.

Comment: @Mike, let's see:  the standard mapping, phi, is defined and analytic everywhere except at z=-i, but since the inputs are f(z) which never achieve -i, phi(f(z)) is analytic everywhere, so it's entire.  As mentioned before, phi(f(z)) is bounded.  By Liouville's theorem, phi(f(z)) is constant.  How can I make the jump and conclude that f(z) itself is constant?

Comment: $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: Ok, got it now.  Thanks so much for your patience and help :)  Have a great night, @Mike.

Comment: Thanks.          ///////////////

Comment: Actually, I would like to discuss part (b) if possible:  as v(x,y) = Im(f(z) tends to zero at infinity, and noting that this function is harmonic on all of C, we look at the mean value property.  The integral over a circle can have arbitrarily large radius R, hence the integrand of this mean value equation tends to zero, by assumption, but then all the points V(z_0) would be zero, as well.  Thus, v(x,y) is identically zero, so f(z) is real.  Another idea is to use the max/min principle, v(x,y) achieves it's max and min on the boundary; since it tends to zero, it must be identically zero.

Comment: Any objections to either of these arguments? Thanks,

Comment: actually, the mean-value property doesn't quite work - the integrating region can grow much faster than my integrand going to zero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part (a) can be done as Mike suggested in the comments (or using the Liouville theorem for harmonic functions), or considering the function $e^{-if}$ which is bounded by $1$ on the whole plane, hence constant.

For part (b), if $\mathsf{Im}(f(z))$ tends to $0$ as $|z|\to\infty$, then there is $R>0$ such that, for $|z|\geq R$, $|\mathsf{Im}(f(z))|\leq 1$.

Take $K=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ :\ |z|\leq 2R\}$. This is a compact set, hence $|\mathsf{Im}(f(z))|$ achieves a maximum on $K$, say $M>0$, but outside $K$, $|\mathsf{Im}(f(z))|\leq 1$, so $|\mathsf{Im}(f(z))|\leq\max\{M,1\}$ on the whole plane, hence it is constant.

Equivalently, set $g=e^{-if}$, then $|g|\to1$ when $|z|\to\infty$, meaning that $g$ is bounded around $\infty$. By Riemann's extension theorem, the function $h(z)=g(1/z)$, bounded around $0$, can be extended holomorphically to $z=0$; therefore the function $g$ extends holomorphically (or at least continuously if you have problems dealing with Riemann surfaces) to a function $\tilde{g}:\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}\to\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $\tilde{g}:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{C}$. But as $\mathbb{S}^2$ is compact, $\tilde{g}$ is bounded and so is $g$, which is then constant and so is $f$.

(or if you know enough about holomorphic functions, on compact Riemann surfaces like $\mathbb{CP}^1=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ there are no non-constant holomorphic functions…)

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much, @wisefool.  Looking at the function e^if is indeed very nice and direct, but I'm glad I got a bit more practice with using conformal mappings, before finding out about your suggestion.  Have a great night.